# facebook login dialogue box taking too much time for opening (iphone)

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

I am using this example for all facebook stuff..

https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API

But my problem is when everytime I am logging in/log out it takes sometime to open up facebook login dialogue box..

that white screen is staying there and there only..

can anyone suggest me what should I do?

Comment: It load a url in web view so will take time, depends on your internet speed.

Comment: saadnib...I have highspeed internet here :(..i dont want that white screen it is staying there nearly 8-9 seconds..:(

Comment: i don't think there is any solution for it, it will take time to load.

Comment: Nothing you can do there rathodrc, Except show a busy indicator animating..:(